# FileTransfer returns error with all properties `null`

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2, cordova-plugins

In my Ionic 2 application I'm taking a picture with `cordova-plugin-camera` where I retrieve the picture by `FILE_URL` (local device's image location) which works well.

This gives me the URL like so when taking a picture with the camera: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/....../1234.jpg`

And like this when selecting an image from the gallery: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%232312`

Now I'm trying to upload this image using `cordova-plugin-file-transfer`.

My upload function is like the following:

```
upload(){
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'file',
        fileName: 'my_image.jpg',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': localStorage.getItem('u:token')}
    }
    alert(this.imageSrc);
    this.fileTransfer.upload(this.imageSrc, encodeURI(this.API_URL), options, true)
        .then(data => {
            alert("d:"+JSON.stringify(data));
        }, err => {
            alert("E:"+JSON.stringify(err));
        });
}
```

But I receive an error object holding the following

```
{
  "code" : "null",
  "source" : "null",
  "target" : "null",
  "http_status" : "null",
  "body" : "null",
  "exception" : "null"
}
```

**Note: no additional erros are being throwm**

Comment: are you sure it is not a server side issue?

Comment: @suraj I'd expect an `http_status` of value `500` if that were the case, or even `404` if it isn't there

Comment: true.. but something like a cors issue will give you null/0 status

Comment: @suraj thought CORS also returned `404`? Not sure though, I'll check

Comment: have you resolved this issues?

Comment: @MuneemHabib yes. Just posted an answer, check it out below.

Comment: what about is body: null
code: 1
exception: null
http_status: null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so the problem was that the Gallery returned a `contentURI` but not a `fileURI` which is needed by the [FileTransfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/). The problem occured both on `content:` and `/storage/` URIs.

I used a bad practice workaround but since it still isn't fixed, I'll share it.

I fixed it by adding the [FilePath](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/)(`cordova-plugin-filepath`).

Below function uses the storage and content URI's and converts them to a filepath.

(Image source global in my case)

```
convertIfAndroidGalleryImage() {
        // android bug, sometimes returns an image starting with content: or /storage/ which won't upload. 
        // Convert to a filepath.
        if(this.imageSrc.startsWith('content') || this.imageSrc.startsWith('/storage/')) {
            if(this.imageSrc.startsWith('/storage/')) {
                this.imageSrc = 'file://'+this.imageSrc;
            }
            this.filePath.resolveNativePath(this.imageSrc).then(filePath => {
                this.imageSrc = filePath;

            }).catch(err => { console.log("error occurred"); });
        }
    }
```

Comment: additional info: Usually I convert my FileURI to base64 based on size of the upload.

Comment: I was doing all things. I wasted much of time that why i am even facing this issue. I just tried it on my app without --livereload and it works like a charm so don't run this plugin with --livereload. Run it on real device.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Where I have used this plugin in the past I would normally pass in a:

```
file:///Path/To/File/
```

Or something like:

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file.txt
```

You can also pass in a data URI like this:

```
data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA....
```

I see you are using the camera plugin have you tried setting the camera options to return a data URL and the sending that?

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
{
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL;
});
```

**Original**

Try constructing your options like this:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();

options.fileKey =  'file',
options.fileName = 'my_image.jpg',
options.headers = {'X-CSRF-Token': localStorage.getItem('u:token')}
```

Then try uploading like this:

```
 var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.upload('file_url', 'endpoint_url', success_callback, fail_callback, options);
```

Comment: 2 problems here, 1: `'FileUploadOptions' only refers to a type but is being used as a value here` and 2: there is no support for the callbacks. (Ionic modified the cordova plugin I guess: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/ )

Comment: Thanks for the link. Hadn't seen that before.

Comment: Just a quick question since I saw your cordova tag as one of your best. Am I using the `imageSrc` correctly? Or should I modify this? (like `content:///` or `file:///` or should it be set to something else) (got a problem atm that serverside receives a null object)

Comment: I have edited my post to answer this. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue when I test app in ionic view, but after I create apk the problem disappeared and no error raised.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and the problem was that the upload url was badly formatted, I put the correct url and it worked for me.

Comment: "It didn't work because I had a typo" isn't a particularly useful answer.  In fact you could probably post that for a large fraction of "it's not working" questions.